# remove redundant if condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a python script that uses multiple  `if statement` conditions in order to allow the user to filter the dataframe and return the required results.

The problem is that I have multiple conditions that make the script to be very slow.

My question is how to remove or reduce the **redundant if conditions** and make the conditions **dynamic** based on the selection of the user for columns that he wants to filter.

code:

```
    col1_ch,col2_ch,col3_ch = st.sidebar.columns(3)
            with col1_ch:
                adv_searchcheckbox_name_nickname = st.checkbox("Name or Nickname or Mother name",value = False,key=1)
                adv_searchcheckbox_gender = st.checkbox("Gender",value = False,key=2)
                adv_searchcheckbox_status_type = st.checkbox("Status type",value = False,key=3)
                adv_searchcheckbox_country = st.checkbox("Country",value = False,key=4)
                adv_searchcheckbox_bd = st.checkbox("Date Of Birth",value = False,key=5)
            
    if adv_searchcheckbox_name_nickname:
         col1, col2,col3 = st.sidebar.columns(3)
         with col1:
             name_search = st.text_input("name")
         with col2:
             nickname_search = st.text_input("nickname")
         with col3:
             Mother_name_search = st.text_input("mother name")
        
    if adv_searchcheckbox_gender:
        radio_gender = st.sidebar.radio(label="Gender", options=["M","F"])
    
    if st.sidebar.button("search"):
                # *******************name nickname mothername checkbox***************
                # . only name/nickname/mother name  is checked
         if adv_searchcheckbox_name_nickname and not adv_searchcheckbox_gender and not adv_searchcheckbox_status_type and not adv_searchcheckbox_country and not adv_searchcheckbox_bd:
                    # if name is specified but not the nickname and mother name 
              if name_search != '' and nickname_search == '' and Mother_name_search =='':
                        df_result_search = df[df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)]
                        
                    # if nickname is specified but not the name and mother name 
              elif nickname_search != ''and name_search == '' and  Mother_name_search == '':
                        df_result_search = df[df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)]
                        
                    # if mother name is specified but not the name and nickname 
              elif Mother_name_search != '' and name_search == '' and nickname_search == '':
                        df_result_search = df[df['mother_name'].str.contains(Mother_name_search, case=False, na=False)]
                        
                    # if both name and nickname are specified
              elif name_search != '' and nickname_search != '' and Mother_name_search!='':
                        df_result_search = df[(df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False))]
                
                    # if both name and mother_name are specified
              elif name_search != '' and Mother_name_search!='' and nickname_search == '' :
                        df_result_search = df[(df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)) & df['mother_name'].str.contains(Mother_name_search, case=False, na=False)]
                
                    # if both nickname and mother_name are specified
              elif nickname_search != '' and Mother_name_search!='' and name_search == '':
                        df_result_search = df[(df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)) & df['mother_name'].str.contains(Mother_name_search, case=False, na=False)]
                    
                    # if user does not enter anything
              else:
                  st.warning('Please enter at least a name or a nickname or mother name ')
                # *******************name nickname mothername checkbox***************
                
                # *******************gender checkbox***************
         elif  adv_searchcheckbox_gender and  adv_searchcheckbox_name_nickname  and not adv_searchcheckbox_status_type and not adv_searchcheckbox_country and not adv_searchcheckbox_bd:
                    # if name is specified but not the nickname and mother name 
              if name_search != '' and radio_gender !='' and nickname_search == '' and Mother_name_search =='':
                        df_result_search = df[df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False) & (df['gender'] ==(radio_gender))]
                    
                    # if nickname is specified but not the name and mother name 
              elif nickname_search != '' and  radio_gender !=''and name_search == '' and  Mother_name_search == '':
                        df_result_search = df[df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)& (df['gender'] ==(radio_gender))]
                    
                    # if mother name is specified but not the name and nickname 
              elif Mother_name_search != '' and radio_gender !='' and name_search == '' and nickname_search == '' :
                        df_result_search = df[df['mother_name'].str.contains(Mother_name_search, case=False, na=False)& (df['gender'] ==(radio_gender))]
                    
                    # if both name and nickname are specified
              elif name_search != '' and nickname_search != ''  and radio_gender !=''and Mother_name_search=='':
                        df_result_search = df[(df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['gender'] ==(radio_gender))]
                    
                    # if both name and mother name are specified
              elif name_search != ''   and radio_gender !=''and Mother_name_search!='' and nickname_search == '':
                        df_result_search = df[(df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False))  & (df['mother_name'].str.contains(Mother_name_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['gender'] ==(radio_gender))]
                    
                    # if both nickname and mother name are specified
              elif nickname_search != ''  and radio_gender !=''and Mother_name_search!='' and name_search == '':
                        df_result_search = df[(df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['mother_name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['gender'] ==(radio_gender))]
                    
                    # if all  name nickname and mother name are specified
              elif nickname_search != ''  and radio_gender !=''and Mother_name_search!='' and name_search != '':
                        df_result_search = df[(df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['mother_name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['gender'] ==(radio_gender))]
                    
                    # if user does not enter anything
              else:
                        st.warning('Specify at least 1 input ')
                    # *******************gender checkbox***************
st.dataframe(df_result_search)
```

**This is just for the first 2 columns**

Comment: This is terribly structured code. Please apply DRY (Do-not-Repeat-Yourself) principle. Isolate expressions which appear multiple times in your code and then calculate them only once and put their result to a local/temporary variable. For example `df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)` is calculated always when `if name_search != ''` (btw. use `if name_search` instead, which is more pythonic). So calculate it only once. Once you simplify the code, you can start thinking about optimizations.

Comment: @HiFilethebestfilemanager i know that is  a bad structure that is why i am asking this question.... and i did not understand what you meant by `Isolate expressions which appear multiple times in your code and then calculate them only once and put their result to a local/temporary variable`.

Comment: I meant you should put it to a variable. `if name_search: name_match = df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)` and then reuse the `name_match` variable instead of the full expression. However after looking more thoroughly at your code, I suggested step-by-step approach as you can see in my answer. This is even better. Anyway, DRY principle is one of the most important rules in programming, keep it in mind and everytime you find yourself writing the same expression twice, think about DRY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter it step by step. In each step you narrow down the final dataframe (stored to `result` variable) by applying just a single condition.

```
result = df  # initialize the result and narrow-down the result in each of the following conditions

if name_search: # note: do not use name_search != ''
    result = result[result['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)]

if nickname_search:
    result = result[result['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)]

if mother_name_search:
    result = result[result['mother_name'].str.contains(mother_name_search, case=False, na=False)]

# ... etc. add more conditions as you need
```

I think you got the idea now.

Comment: i tried your answer  but it display the below error:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name_search' referenced before assignment
Traceback:

File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 554, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "test_func.py", line 485, in <module>
    main()
File "test_func.py", line 307, in main
    if name_search: # note: do not use name_search != ''`

Note that each filter is optional and the user can select or not

Comment: Oh, common, you certainly can adjust the snippet I provided so that it does not produce the errors. I just did not want to rewrite all of your code. I only showed the way to avoid such complex a duplicated `if else` statements. Of course you need to prepend the part with `if adv_searchcheckbox_name_nickname: ` etc... and init all the variables which are used.

Comment: yes sorry i did not reply again but i figure it out thank you

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be a good use case for the new [pattern matching feature in Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching).

Apart from that you are using the same variables over and over again in your is/elif statements (eg. `nickname_search`, `name_search`, ...).

You could define their content upfront with something like:

```
name_search_empty = ''
```

That way you could at least avoid the redundant comparison operators.